# Need to Destroy the window created from another class

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have created my window in the driver code my first window is "Ui_Login" , through events and signal i can switch from "UI_Login" to "Ui_signup" or "Ui_forgetpass" but when i try to switch it back it siwtches easily but i cannot destroy the previous window which was created from "Ui_Login" Methods. How to destroy that particular window while i am inside "Ui_signup" or "Ui_forgetpass" class because i cannot access the window object from here please help me out.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_ForgetPassword(object):
    def setupUi(self, ForgetPassword):
        ForgetPassword.setObjectName("ForgetPassword")
        ForgetPassword.resize(449, 567)
        ForgetPassword.setStyleSheet("QDialog{\n"
"background-color: rgb(197, 210, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(ForgetPassword)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 10, 211, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("Qlabel{\n"
"font-color:rgb(255, 255, 255)\n"
"}")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(ForgetPassword)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 301, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lblUser = QtWidgets.QLabel(ForgetPassword)
        self.lblUser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 270, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lblUser.setFont(font)
        self.lblUser.setObjectName("lblUser")
        self.lblCode = QtWidgets.QLabel(ForgetPassword)
        self.lblCode.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 340, 121, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lblCode.setFont(font)
        self.lblCode.setObjectName("lblCode")
        self.txtcode = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(ForgetPassword)
        self.txtcode.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 330, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.txtcode.setFont(font)
        self.txtcode.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{\n"
"border-radius:10px;\n"
"}")
        self.txtcode.setMaxLength(6)
        self.txtcode.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.txtcode.setObjectName("txtcode")
        self.btnSubmit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(ForgetPassword)
        self.btnSubmit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 430, 331, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.btnSubmit.setFont(font)
        self.btnSubmit.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"background-color: rgb(36, 96, 167);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius:10px;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover\n"
"{\n"
"background:#0094ff;\n"
"text-transform:uppercase;\n"
"}")
        self.btnSubmit.setObjectName("btnSubmit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(ForgetPassword)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 110, 191, 161))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/forgetpass.png);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.txtuser = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(ForgetPassword)
        self.txtuser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 270, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.txtuser.setFont(font)
        self.txtuser.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{\n"
"border-radius:10px;\n"
"}")
        self.txtuser.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.txtuser.setObjectName("txtuser")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(ForgetPassword)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(136, 380, 151, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
"color:darkblue;\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom|QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.btnLogin = QtWidgets.QPushButton(ForgetPassword)
        self.btnLogin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 500, 331, 51))
        self.btnLogin.clicked.connect(self.go_to_Login)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.btnLogin.setFont(font)
        self.btnLogin.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"background-color: rgb(36, 96, 167);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius:10px;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover\n"
"{\n"
"background:#0094ff;\n"
"text-transform:uppercase;\n"
"}")
        self.btnLogin.setObjectName("btnLogin")

        self.retranslateUi(ForgetPassword)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ForgetPassword)

    def retranslateUi(self, ForgetPassword):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        ForgetPassword.setWindowTitle(_translate("ForgetPassword", "Dialog"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("ForgetPassword", "Forget Password"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("ForgetPassword", "Enter your username to reset password:"))
        self.lblUser.setText(_translate("ForgetPassword", "Username:"))
        self.lblCode.setText(_translate("ForgetPassword", "Recovery Code:"))
        self.txtcode.setPlaceholderText(_translate("ForgetPassword", "6 digit pin"))
        self.btnSubmit.setText(_translate("ForgetPassword", "Submit"))
        self.txtuser.setPlaceholderText(_translate("ForgetPassword", "Enter Username"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("ForgetPassword", "Complete!"))
        self.btnLogin.setText(_translate("ForgetPassword", "Go To Login"))

    def go_to_Login(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.Login = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_Login()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.Login)
        self.Login.show()

class Ui_SignUp(object):
    def setupUi(self, SignUp):
        SignUp.setObjectName("SignUp")
        SignUp.resize(449, 568)
        SignUp.setStyleSheet("QDialog{\n"
                             "background-color: rgb(197, 210, 255);\n"
                             "}")
        self.txtuser = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(SignUp)
        self.txtuser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 180, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.txtuser.setFont(font)
        self.txtuser.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{\n"
                                   "border-radius:10px;\n"
                                   "}")
        self.txtuser.setObjectName("txtuser")
        self.lblUser = QtWidgets.QLabel(SignUp)
        self.lblUser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 190, 81, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lblUser.setFont(font)
        self.lblUser.setObjectName("lblUser")
        self.lbllogin = QtWidgets.QLabel(SignUp)
        self.lbllogin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 0, 171, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lbllogin.setFont(font)
        self.lbllogin.setStyleSheet("Qlabel{\n"
                                    "font-color:rgb(255, 255, 255)\n"
                                    "}")
        self.lbllogin.setObjectName("lbllogin")
        self.lblEmail = QtWidgets.QLabel(SignUp)
        self.lblEmail.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 260, 71, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lblEmail.setFont(font)
        self.lblEmail.setObjectName("lblEmail")
        self.txtmail = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(SignUp)
        self.txtmail.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 250, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.txtmail.setFont(font)
        self.txtmail.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{\n"
                                   "border-radius:10px;\n"
                                   "}")
        self.txtmail.setObjectName("txtmail")
        self.txtpass = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(SignUp)
        self.txtpass.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 310, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.txtpass.setFont(font)
        self.txtpass.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{\n"
                                   "border-radius:10px;\n"
                                   "}")
        self.txtpass.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.txtpass.setObjectName("txtpass")
        self.txtconpass = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(SignUp)
        self.txtconpass.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 370, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.txtconpass.setFont(font)
        self.txtconpass.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{\n"
                                      "border-radius:10px;\n"
                                      "}")
        self.txtconpass.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.txtconpass.setObjectName("txtconpass")
        self.lblPass = QtWidgets.QLabel(SignUp)
        self.lblPass.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 320, 73, 19))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lblPass.setFont(font)
        self.lblPass.setObjectName("lblPass")
        self.lblConfirmPass = QtWidgets.QLabel(SignUp)
        self.lblConfirmPass.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 380, 141, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lblConfirmPass.setFont(font)
        self.lblConfirmPass.setObjectName("lblConfirmPass")
        self.btnsign = QtWidgets.QPushButton(SignUp)
        self.btnsign.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 460, 331, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.btnsign.setFont(font)
        self.btnsign.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
                                   "background-color: rgb(36, 96, 167);\n"
                                   "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                   "border-radius:10px;\n"
                                   "}\n"
                                   "QPushButton:hover\n"
                                   "{\n"
                                   "background:#0094ff;\n"
                                   "text-transform:uppercase;\n"
                                   "}")
        self.btnsign.setObjectName("btnsign")
        self.txtFirst = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(SignUp)
        self.txtFirst.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 60, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.txtFirst.setFont(font)
        self.txtFirst.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{\n"
                                    "border-radius:10px;\n"
                                    "}\n"
                                    "")
        self.txtFirst.setObjectName("txtFirst")
        self.lblFirst = QtWidgets.QLabel(SignUp)
        self.lblFirst.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 70, 81, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lblFirst.setFont(font)
        self.lblFirst.setObjectName("lblFirst")
        self.lblLast = QtWidgets.QLabel(SignUp)
        self.lblLast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 130, 81, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lblLast.setFont(font)
        self.lblLast.setObjectName("lblLast")
        self.txtLast = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(SignUp)
        self.txtLast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 120, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.txtLast.setFont(font)
        self.txtLast.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{\n"
                                   "border-radius:10px;\n"
                                   "}")
        self.txtLast.setObjectName("txtLast")
        self.lblimgfirst = QtWidgets.QLabel(SignUp)
        self.lblimgfirst.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 51, 51))
        self.lblimgfirst.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/default.png);")
        self.lblimgfirst.setText("")
        self.lblimgfirst.setObjectName("lblimgfirst")
        self.lblimglast = QtWidgets.QLabel(SignUp)
        self.lblimglast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 120, 51, 51))
        self.lblimglast.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/default.png);")
        self.lblimglast.setText("")
        self.lblimglast.setObjectName("lblimglast")
        self.lblimguser = QtWidgets.QLabel(SignUp)
        self.lblimguser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 180, 51, 51))
        self.lblimguser.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/default.png);")
        self.lblimguser.setText("")
        self.lblimguser.setObjectName("lblimguser")
        self.lblimgmail = QtWidgets.QLabel(SignUp)
        self.lblimgmail.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 250, 51, 51))
        self.lblimgmail.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/Mail-512.png);")
        self.lblimgmail.setText("")
        self.lblimgmail.setObjectName("lblimgmail")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(SignUp)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 310, 0, 13))
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/login1.png);")
        self.label_5.setText("")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.lblimgconf = QtWidgets.QLabel(SignUp)
        self.lblimgconf.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 370, 51, 51))
        self.lblimgconf.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/login1.png);")
        self.lblimgconf.setText("")
        self.lblimgconf.setObjectName("lblimgconf")
        self.lblimgpass = QtWidgets.QLabel(SignUp)
        self.lblimgpass.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 310, 51, 51))
        self.lblimgpass.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/login1.png);")
        self.lblimgpass.setText("")
        self.lblimgpass.setObjectName("lblimgpass")
        self.lblreg = QtWidgets.QLabel(SignUp)
        self.lblreg.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 410, 231, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.lblreg.setFont(font)
        self.lblreg.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
                                  "color: rgb(0, 0, 127);\n"
                                  "}")
        self.lblreg.setObjectName("lblreg")
        self.btnLogin = QtWidgets.QPushButton(SignUp)
        self.btnLogin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 520, 331, 41))
        self.btnLogin.clicked.connect(self.go_to_Login)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.btnLogin.setFont(font)
        self.btnLogin.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
                                    "background-color: rgb(36, 96, 167);\n"
                                    "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                    "border-radius:10px;\n"
                                    "}\n"
                                    "QPushButton:hover\n"
                                    "{\n"
                                    "background:#0094ff;\n"
                                    "text-transform:uppercase;\n"
                                    "}")
        self.btnLogin.setObjectName("btnLogin")


        self.retranslateUi(SignUp)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SignUp)

    def retranslateUi(self, SignUp):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        SignUp.setWindowTitle(_translate("SignUp", "SignUp"))
        self.lblUser.setText(_translate("SignUp", "Username:"))
        self.lbllogin.setText(_translate("SignUp", "Sign Up Form"))
        self.lblEmail.setText(_translate("SignUp", "E-mail:"))
        self.lblPass.setText(_translate("SignUp", "Password:"))
        self.lblConfirmPass.setText(_translate("SignUp", "Confirm Password:"))
        self.btnsign.setText(_translate("SignUp", "Sign Me Up"))
        self.lblFirst.setText(_translate("SignUp", "First Name:"))
        self.lblLast.setText(_translate("SignUp", "Last Name:"))
        self.lblreg.setText(_translate("SignUp", "Registration Complete!"))
        self.btnLogin.setText(_translate("SignUp", "Go To Login"))

    def go_to_Login(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.Login = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_Login()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.Login)
        self.Login.show()



class Ui_Login(object):
    def setupUi(self, Login):             #Login Body
        Login.setObjectName("Login")
        Login.resize(449, 555)
        Login.setStyleSheet("QDialog{\n"
"background-color: rgb(197, 210, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Login)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 10, 141, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("Qlabel{\n"
"font-color:rgb(255, 255, 255)\n"
"}")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Login)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 70, 301, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lblUser = QtWidgets.QLabel(Login)
        self.lblUser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 220, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lblUser.setFont(font)
        self.lblUser.setObjectName("lblUser")
        self.lblPass = QtWidgets.QLabel(Login)
        self.lblPass.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 290, 91, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lblPass.setFont(font)
        self.lblPass.setObjectName("lblPass")
        self.txtUser = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Login)
        self.txtUser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 220, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.txtUser.setFont(font)
        self.txtUser.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{\n"
"border-radius:10px;\n"
"}")
        self.txtUser.setObjectName("txtUser")
        self.txtPass = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Login)
        self.txtPass.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 280, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.txtPass.setFont(font)
        self.txtPass.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{\n"
"border-radius:10px;\n"
"}")
        self.txtPass.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.txtPass.setObjectName("txtPass")
        self.btnlogin = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Login)                             #For Login button
        self.btnlogin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 380, 331, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.btnlogin.setFont(font)
        self.btnlogin.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"                 
"background-color: rgb(36, 96, 167);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius:10px;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover\n"
"{\n"
"background:#0094ff;\n"
"text-transform:uppercase;\n"
"}")
        self.btnlogin.setObjectName("btnlogin")
        self.btnsignup = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Login)
        self.btnsignup.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 450, 331, 51))
        self.btnlogin.clicked.connect(self.on_click)   #button function calling (login button)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.btnsignup.setFont(font)
        self.btnsignup.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"                  #For Sign Up
"background-color: rgb(36, 96, 167);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius:10px;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover\n"
"{\n"
"background:#0094ff;\n"
"text-transform:uppercase;\n"
"}")
        self.btnsignup.setObjectName("btnsignup")
        self.forgetpass = QtWidgets.QCommandLinkButton(Login)
        self.forgetpass.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 510, 141, 41))
        self.btnsignup.clicked.connect(self.on_click_sigup)              #button function calling (create account button)
        self.forgetpass.setStyleSheet("QCommandLinkButton{\n"
"color:darkblue;\n"
"}")
        self.forgetpass.setObjectName("forgetpass")
        self.forgetpass.clicked.connect(self.onclick_forgetpas)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Login)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 100, 121, 91))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("image: url(C:/Users/Fatima Ali/OneDrive/Bureau/Login/login-user-icon.png);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Login)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 330, 231, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 127);\n"
"}")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")                    #Login successfully
        self.label_4.hide()                                    #Hide Login successfully label


        self.retranslateUi(Login)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Login)

    def retranslateUi(self, Login):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Login.setWindowTitle(_translate("Login", "Login"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Login", "Login Form"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Login", "Enter your username and password to log on:"))
        self.lblUser.setText(_translate("Login", "Username:"))
        self.lblPass.setText(_translate("Login", "Password:"))
        self.btnlogin.setText(_translate("Login", "Login"))
        self.btnsignup.setText(_translate("Login", "Create Account"))
        self.forgetpass.setText(_translate("Login", "Forget Password?"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Login", "Successfully Login!"))

    def on_click(self):
        """This will show that the person is successfully Login after login button is clicked"""
        self.label_4.show()

    def on_click_sigup(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.SignUp = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_SignUp()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.SignUp)
        self.SignUp.show()
        Login.destroy()

    def onclick_forgetpas(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.ForgetPassword = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_ForgetPassword()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.ForgetPassword)
        self.ForgetPassword.show()
        Login.destroy()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Login = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Login()
    ui.setupUi(Login)
    Login.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The alternate solution is to pass to an instance of Main Class(The UI class to destroyed)  and into another class and from there it can be destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to put everything in the Ui_ classes I would use these only for setting up the visual layout of the user interface without worrying what should happen when the buttons are clicked. Furthermore, I would create sub-classes of `QDialog` (one for for each of the login, sign-up and forgotten password dialogs) and move the functionality of opening and closing the dialogs to these sub-classes.

To illustrate what I mean, in the minimal example below I have created two classes for the login and sign-up dialogs with some minimal code for navigating between these two dialogs.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Ui_SignUp(object):
    def setupUi(self, SignUp):
        SignUp.setWindowTitle('Sign up')
        SignUp.resize(449, 568)

        self.btnsign = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Sign me up', SignUp)
        self.btnsign.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 460, 331, 41))

        self.btnLogin = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Go to Login', SignUp)
        self.btnLogin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 520, 331, 41))


class Ui_Login(object):
    def setupUi(self, Login): 
        Login.setWindowTitle('Login')            
        Login.resize(449, 555)
        self.btnlogin = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Login', Login)   
        self.btnlogin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 380, 331, 51))

        self.btnsignup = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Create Account', Login)
        self.btnsignup.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 450, 331, 51))


class LoginDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Login()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnlogin.clicked.connect(self.login)
        self.ui.btnsignup.clicked.connect(self.signup)

    def login(self):
        print('login user')

    def signup(self):
        print('signup clicked: open dialog')
        signup_dialog = SignUpDialog(self)
        signup_dialog.open()
        # rather than destroying the login dialog it's just being hidden
        self.hide()
        # show login dialog when signup_dialog is finished
        signup_dialog.finished.connect(self.show)


class SignUpDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # setting the Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose attribute deletes the dialog once it's finished
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
        self.ui = Ui_SignUp()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnLogin.clicked.connect(self.login_clicked)
        self.ui.btnsign.clicked.connect(self.signup)

    def login_clicked(self):
        print('login clicked: leave dialog')
        self.done(0)

    def signup(self):
        print('signup button clicked')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    Login = LoginDialog()
    Login.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: The answer was very useful for the problem I was facing, it helped me improve the code structure, thanks!